# IF Statements in MySQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to perform the following IF statement:

```
select s.*
from salespeople s
if (s.supervisor >= 1) end if;
```

However, it is throwing an error. I have the doc on IF's here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

My Table looks like this:

```
Salespeople
-----------
SalesID, Firstname, Lastname, Supervisor
```

Where supervisor contain INT records. Basically I am trying to list all the SalesID's that have at least one supervisor.

Comment: Note you where using `MySQL` in other questions, you've linked to `SQL Server` (a Transact SQL Server page, to be more precise) in this question and you've tagged the question as a general `SQL` question :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're confusing `WHERE` with `IF` here; instead, try:

```
SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE Supervisor >= 1;
```

I'm slightly confused regarding the actual data that can be in the `Supervisor` field (beyond it being an integer); if I were to setup the table, I would have the column `null` if it doesn't have a related supervisor; if that is the case in your table as well, you'll want to try the following instead:

```
SELECT * FROM Salespeople WHERE Supervisor IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: If you are going to make recommendations on database redesigns, at least make good ones.  If a person can have more than one supervisor, which is implied by the question, and a supervisor can supervise more than one person, which is a reasonable assumption, that's a many to many relationship and the database design should reflect that.

Comment: @DanBracuk I didn't make any recommendations on redesigning the user's database; I only stated that if I had made a table with the same columns that they used, I would have been using `null` and not `0` and was assuming they may have done the same (considering they didn't state what they used). If I *were* to recommend a redesign, which I would only do if there were more context to the question, I would do exactly as you stated and describe a relationship-table.